# css masonry grid transfer border to the next column

Tags: css

I have a masonry grid to display products and in some cases the first item's border move to the next column. It doesn't happen always and I can't find the reason for this to happen.
Link to the page:
http://en.naaman.b24online.com/b2c-products/tsb-163746/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a wrapper around each box, so the box with border is inside and cant be breaked

Comment: I tried to create a div around it. Not helping. Probably there is something in the current css that cause it.

Comment: I tried it on your site, you just need to give the wrapper of each element 
   `-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found that the height of row of the pins (defined as #columns) is too short. I added the height for the different screen sizes and it seem to work.
Not sure why the row is not taking it's full height.